# No google API build target in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-api

Can anyone help with the following please?

I am developing a Google maps based android app, however I don't have the google api's build targets available in either the initial setup menu or the preferences > android route.

All that appears in the build targets list are the normal android versions but nothing from google.

I've ran the SDK manager to check if there's an update, all that's available is the windows caching service. Nothing google related at all.

the problem stems from eclipse erroring the com.android imports however I have the manifest.xml setup so far as I'm aware.

I am using eclipse helios 3.6.0 with ADT on a win 7 machine.

Can anyone tell me where the problem might be?

Thanks alot

Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure your version of ADT is updated (Help -> Check for Updates).  Then, open the SDK Manager (Window -> Android SDK Manager).  Within each of the API levels (e.g., "Android 3.0 (API 11)"), you will see SDK  Platform, Samples for SDK, and Google APIs by Google Inc.  That last one is the one you want to get and it should say installed on the right side.

Within the AndroidManifest.xml file, you need to have the following inside the application tag:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Comment: That done it for me. It wasn't installed and just needed an update. thanks for this. Pete

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. When you run the Android SDK manager from windows it tells you it has all these things installed (including the google APIs). However when you run the manager (Window menu) from within Eclipse it says they're not installed. I just installed them through eclipse and it worked fine.